# Code only outputs std::vector one time instead of wanted multiple times

Tags: c++

So my problem is the following: I want to program a basic game of life simulation. Therefore I am using std::vector to save the current state and calculate the next state. All put together in a while(). I am doing std::cout for every value, formated as a matrix. The problem is, that I only get one "matrix" as an output, instead of expected multiple.

I've also tried to output text after calculating the next state (so before and after the nextCells=currentCells), which didn't work, while outputting text within the calculating for() loop works.

I don't know what to do anymore. Appreciate any kind of help!

I've tried to output text after calculating the next state (so before and after the nextCells=currentCells), which didn't work, while outputting text within the calculating for() loop works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DIMX 10
#define DIMY 10

int countCells(std::vector<std::vector<int>> currentGrid, int x, int y);

int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> currentCells(DIMX, std::vector<int>(DIMY));
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> nextCells(DIMX, std::vector<int>(DIMY));
    int count = 0;

    nextCells = currentCells;

    while(true) {
        count++;
        for(int i=0;i<=DIMX-1;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=DIMY-1;j++) {
                std::cout << currentCells[i][j];
                std::cout.flush();
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=DIMX-1;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=DIMY-1;j++) {
                int aliveCells = countCells(currentCells, i, j);
                if(currentCells[i][j]==0) {
                    if(aliveCells==3) {
                        nextCells[i][j]=1;
                    } else {
                        nextCells[i][j]=0;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(aliveCells>3) {
                        nextCells[i][j]=0;
                    } else if(aliveCells<2) {
                        nextCells[i][j]=0;
                    } else {
                        nextCells[i][j]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        currentCells = nextCells;

        if(count>=5) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
int countCells(std::vector<std::vector<int>> currentGrid, int x, int y) {
    int aliveCounter;
    if(x==DIMX || x==0 || y==DIMY || y==0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if(currentGrid[x-1][y-1]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x-1][y]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x-1][y+1]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x][y-1]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x][y+1]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x+1][y-1]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x+1][y]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    } else if(currentGrid[x+1][y+1]==1) {
        aliveCounter++;
    }
    return aliveCounter;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialise `aliveCounter`, which summons the Undefined Behaviour. And once you’ve initialised it to zero, it will never be greater than one.

Comment: You’re also indexing outside the upper boundaries of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produces an out of vector-range exception,  For optimization reasons  the exception may not throw in release mode. 
When countCells gets called for y = 9 or x = 9

```
currentGrid[x+1][y+1]
```

is out of range.
Notice that

```
  v = std::vector<int>(10,0) can be called from v[0] to v[9]; not v[10],
```

which would be out of range.